# Is behavior of expect_after/expect_background in proc different than when called globally?

Tags: tcl, expect

I'm automating some work with expect, and have something like the following:

```
# procedure to set background and after patterns
proc foo {} {
    expect_after {
        -re $regex1 {puts "Matched regex1"; send $command_to_run; exp_continue}
        timeout {exp_continue}
    }
    expect_background {
        -re $regex2 {do other things; exp_continue}
        -re $regex3 {and more different things; exp_continue}
        timeout {exp_continue}
    }
}

spawn $thing
foo
expect_user {
    -ex "stahp" {exit}
}
```

This hangs indefinitely after `expect_after` pattern is matched (and the associated body is run).  However, if I move the `expect_after` and `expect_background` patterns out of the procedure, then it runs as I, well, expected.

Why does it behave differently when put in a procedure?

Comment: Oooh, good question. This is rather further down the Expect subtleties road than I've ever examined…

Comment: I wonder if you need `global spawn_id` in your proc...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to glenn jackman for the idea!  It seems that when called in a procedure, `expect_after`, `expect_background`, and probably `expect_before` not only look for the spawn_id which is in the global scope, but need it specified.

This works:

```
proc foo {} {
    namespace eval global {
        expect_after {
            -i $spawn_id -re $regex1 {do things}
        }
        expect_background {
            -i $spawn_id -re $regex2 {do more different things}
            -i $spawn_id ...
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone can explain why it needs `-i $spawn_id` that would be great, but here's a fix for anyone running into the same problem.  Adding a `global spawn_id` should also work, but I ended up using this as I have about 5-6 variables, half of which I modify in `foo`.

Comment: `namespace eval foo` evaluates the code in the namespace `foo`, so does `namespace eval global`, it executes the code in the namespace `global`. But because there is no variable called `spawn_id` in `global`, it uses the global namespace `::`.

Comment: Is `global` not equivalent to ::?  I guessed and it seemed content.

Comment: No, it is not. It works because it looks in `::` for the variable.