# Why does expect_after keep checking all spawn_ids?

Tags: tcl, expect

I have a proc that creates a `telnet` connection:

```
proc establishTelnetConnection {...} {
    spawn /usr/bin/telnet
    expect_after {
        eof          {...eof handler...}
        full_buffer  {...full_buffer handler...}
        timeout      {...timeout handler...}
    }
    expect {
        "Login: \$"          {...}
        "Password: \$"       {...}
        "Connection refused" {...}
    }
    return $spawn_id
}
```

The proc establishes a connection and leaves it open for the other procs that send commands through it. The `spawn_id` is a local var inside the procedure and is never changed there.

Now if I open more a few connections (more than one) with `exp_internal 1`, I can see that inside the `expect` commands, **all** `expect_after` patterns are checked, not only the ones associated with the current `spawn_id`. The output looks like following:

```
Current spawn_id: exp50

expect: does "abcd\r\nPassword: Connection closed by foreign host.\r\r\n" (spawn_id exp44) match full buffer full_buffer? no
expect: does "abcd\r\nPassword: Connection closed by foreign host.\r\r\n" (spawn_id exp43) match full buffer full_buffer? no
expect: does "abcd\r\nPassword: Connection closed by foreign host.\r\r\n" (spawn_id exp42) match full buffer full_buffer? no
expect: does "abcd\r\nPassword: Connection closed by foreign host.\r\r\n" (spawn_id exp41) match full buffer full_buffer? no
```

Which means that `expect` goes through the old (non-closed) connections (`exp41` - `exp44`) and tries to match against the patterns defined in their respective `expect_after` commands. But I find this behavior strange - I would expect it to match against the patterns defined for the current `spawn_id` (which is `exp50` in this case).

Why is it so?

The reason I'm asking is that after doing these tricks with spawn ids, expect completely freezes without giving any error message.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing [Is behavior of expect_after/expect_background in proc different than when called globally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16848126/is-behavior-of-expect-after-expect-background-in-proc-different-than-when-called).

I believe you may need to specify the `spawn_id` in each `expect_after` pattern, with `-i $spawn_id`.

```
proc establishTelnetConnection {...} {
    spawn /usr/bin/telnet
    expect_after {
        -i $spawn_id eof          {...eof handler...}
        -i $spawn_id full_buffer  {...full_buffer handler...}
        -i $spawn_id timeout      {...timeout handler...}
    }
    expect {
        "Login: \$"          {...}
        "Password: \$"       {...}
        "Connection refused" {...}
    }
    return $spawn_id
}
```

Comment: zekei, thank you for your answer. Though I work for a different company today, I hope your answer will help other folks who have run into this issue.

Comment: I totally missed how old this question was! Not a problem.